# Find specific class out of multiple in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a js file that creates a ripple touch effect when you click an object. I want to assign a class to the element in the html code that is simply a color code like #f6ac32, and then create a function in Javascript/jQuery that can pick out that color code and create a variable out of it that I can later use (to change the color of the ripple effect). Is this possible?

Here is what I've made (check out the comment in $('.ripple').mousedown(function) ) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var rplObj,
 x,
 y,
 ink,
 color,
 rplDelTimer;



//fade out ripple when unclicked
$('.ripple').mouseup(function() {
 $('.ink').css({'opacity':'0'});
 delRipple();
})

//Delete ripple element one second after last click
function delRipple() {
 rplDelTimer = setTimeout(function() {
  $('.ink').remove();
 }, 1000)
}

$('body').mousemove(function(e){
 //update mouse coordinates when it is moved
 x = e.pageX;
 y = e.pageY;
})



$('.ripple').mousedown(function(){
 rplObj = $(this);
 color = "#FFF"; //I want this to dynamically change depending on the class written in html
 rippleClosed();
})



function rippleClosed() {
 rplObj.prepend('<span class="ink"></span>'); //create ripple  
 ink = rplObj.find('.ink'); //create variable for ink span
 ink.css('background',color); //set ripple color to color variable

 //set diameter of ripple
 if(!ink.height() && !ink.width()) {
  //set diameter to parents width/height (whichever is larger)
  d = Math.max(rplObj.outerWidth(), rplObj.outerHeight());
  ink.css({height: d, width: d});
 }

 //set coordinates of ripple using position of mouse defined earlier
 x = x - rplObj.offset().left - ink.width()/2;
 y = y - rplObj.offset().top - ink.height()/2;
 
 //set the position and animate the expansion
 ink.css({top: y+'px', left: x+'px'}).css({'transform':'scale(1.8)'});
 
 //reset ripple deletion timer
 clearTimeout(rplDelTimer);
}
  
})
```

```css
div {
  background: #199ee3;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.ripple {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.ink {
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 100%;
 opacity: .4;
 transform: scale(0);
 -moz-transition: all  1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all  1s ease;
 transition: all  1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ripple"></div>
<p>Click the rectangle!</p>
```

Also, if you're curious, [here's](https://56518e103ad0a33e1e59010571f0abeef940717a.googledrive.com/host/0B4rWYiw5-JZtfnZDNTdxZEZ1cTdDTEdUbWh0T0ttdkFEQTlDRFlUZlBLYjQtaFNBdkhndEE/#) the site I'm using it for

Comment: where to pick up the color code

Comment: I want to write the color code as a class in the html element, for example: <div class="ripple #FFF"></div>

Comment: My question is actually really simple, I just need that html class to be turned into a JS variable, without including any other classes that might be attached to the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use classes, use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). You can store all kinds of arbitrary information directly on DOM nodes this way.

```js
$('div').on('click', function () {
  var ripple = $(this).data('ripple');
  
  alert(ripple);
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #199ee3;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div data-ripple="#FFF"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that feature even existed!